# div not contains any string from an Array - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if a div not contains string from an array.
lets say the array is:

var vals = ["a","b","c"]

I want to hide all the divs that don't contain any of these strings.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I only have a way to hide all divs that not contain a specific string: $('.provider_body:not(:contains("a string"))')

Comment: Hmmm...perhaps you'll want to look at $.each() https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ or maybe even a for loop.

Comment: I already thought about using both each and for, but i thought maybe there's a way to do it with a jquery single liner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***DEMO*** http://jsfiddle.net/GS8QD/5/

```
var vals = ["a", "b", "c"];
var $divs = $('.container div');
$divs.each(function () {
    var $currDiv = $(this);
    $.each(vals, function (index, value) {
        if ($currDiv.is(':contains(' + value + ')') && $currDiv.is(":visible")) {
            $currDiv.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

**Explanation:** Loop through each div from the collection of divs & inside the loop have another loop which loops through each value in the array. Now check if the div contains the value & then hide it.

Comment: this was the most similar answer to what I did:    $(".provider_body").each(function () {
        var str = $(this).html();
        var a = values.some(function (itm) {
            return (str.indexOf(itm) != -1)
        });
        if (a == false) $(this).hide(); else $(this).show(); 
    });

Answer (score 2):

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var vals = ["a","b","c"];
           $("div").hide();
          $(document).ready(function () {
             for (index = 0; index < vals.length; ++index) {    
                $("div").hide();     
                $("div p:contains(vals[index])").parent('div').show();
             }   
          });
        </script>
```

Comment: Assuming that there are paragraphs and the OP wants to hide those that are NOT in the index.

Comment: I am sorry . you can use without paragraph p $("div:contains(vals[index])").parent('div').show();

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the divs to show that contain a, b or c you can do this -

```
var vals = ["a", "b", "c"];

$('div:not(:contains('+vals[0]+'),:contains('+vals[1]+'),:contains('+vals[2]+'))').hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/9SJ2h/

Comment: I don't know the number of items in the array, this was just an example